# Synchronizing phone data with online service

Tags: api, windows-phone-7, windows-7

I am trying to build a windows phone application which can synchronize my events on the phone with online service. I can use an api for interacting with the online service.

I am having difficulty understanding how I can synchronize my phone events with the online service.

Can some one please guide me as to how I could go about working on it or some helpful link where I can understand how this actually works??

This is for a school project and for non-commercial purpose only.

Thank you
All help appreciated!!!

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 does not currently provide 3rd party apps with access to information stored in the calendar or contacts. This may be included in Mango, which is set to be released fall/winter 2011, but as of right now you cannot access the events from a custom application.